# Is it possible to replace the loss function in a convolutional neural network with a layer?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I was wondering if it is possible to replace the loss function of a model with a layer having as activation function the loss function. If yes, how will this impact the network? How will the gradient descent work? How can i obtain the prediction if i do this?

Comment: Not required to ask question in stackoverflow instead of meta stack

Comment: loss is computed at end of the network, by calculating difference between predicted class and target. Activation function are here to normalise layer output. If you use in a fully connected layer of size **nb class target** you'll not have weight in the output and u'll not be able to compute weight for next layer. may be i'm wrong